# current_timestamp() cached results at WHERE clause. Is this the expected behavior?

Tags: esper

At Esper online (8.5 - https://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html) It seems that current_timestamp() single row method is acting as a cached one when it is present at WHERE  section. I don’t remember this behavior before (I think it reevaluates with each event).

i.e given:

```
create schema iotEvent(id string, type string, value double);

SELECT current_timestamp().getSecondOfMinute()%2 as zeroorone 
FROM iotEvent 
WHERE current_timestamp().getSecondOfMinute()%2=0
```

and the following event flow:

```
iotEvent={id='A', type="pump", value=1.0}
t=t.plus(1 sec)
iotEvent={id='B', type="dump", value=12.0}
t=t.plus(1 sec)
iotEvent={id='C', type="pump", value=4.0}
t=t.plus(1 sec)
iotEvent={id='A', type="dump", value=15.0}
t=t.plus(1 sec)
iotEvent={id='B', type="pump", value=2.0}
t=t.plus(1 sec)
iotEvent={id='A', type="dump", value=3.0}
```

"zeroorone" at select list iterate values 0,1,0,1,... as expected but the where expression just takes 0 or 1 depending on the initial event result. In this case 0 (so it matches all the time).

On the other hand:

```
SELECT current_timestamp().getSecondOfMinute()%2 as zeroorone 
    FROM iotEvent 
    WHERE current_timestamp().getSecondOfMinute()%2=1
```

Never matches.

We don’t see this behavior in our Esper deployments (v 7). Has anything changed in 8.5 single row methods cache policies?, is this the desired behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug due to the more agressive filter index planning. The doc link is [Compiler Filter Expression Analysis](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.5.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#apicompiler-filterplan). This can be disabled in the compiler settings.

Comment: But any insight about how to change this behavior in the esper online service?  https://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html